# Full Justification for Proportional Fonts

Tags: fonts, align

I am having difficulty getting text to fully justify when I use a proportional font. When I do, I get staggered text. As I understand it, the way emacs generally handles filling is by number of characters.

Is there an easy way to justify proportional fonts or fix this problem?

Aligned version (monofont):
[image]

Proportional font:
[image]

Comment: Could you perhaps include a screenshot, or fake it with text, to *show* what you mean: what you see now and what you would like to see?

Comment: Hey @Drew - does this clarify the question? I've been looking at implementing a function myself, but the (char-width) function seems to return widths in terms of columns, which obviously isn't useful when a character doesn't fill a column. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, thanks. Hopefully someone will have a useful answer for you.

Comment: @strange Do not use `char-width` but `window-text-pixel-size`. Compare `shr-string-pixel-width`.